# difference between infrared radiation and infrared night vision

Tags: electromagnetism, spectroscopy

I need th eanswer that are infrared radiation and infrared night vision are same?. Are Infrared night vision camera use IR rays?, if yes then why we use Infrared LEDs around the lens???
I am totaly confuse about the infrared radiation and infrared night vision camera work....

Comment: Infrarred is just another type of radiation, like visible light is,  they're mostly the same. Now, are "light" and "light vision" the same?

Answer (score 1):

[A small google search shows that you are thinking of the second type of infrared cameras:](http://www.cctvco.com/support-pages/Infrared-Cam.html)

> FLIR cameras are used in a wide variety of private, commercial and industrial settings. Consumers and professionals use them for building inspection, safety, emergency and hazard prevention and identification. The real-time display available on many FLIR camera designs gives the user immediate feedback and allows them to pinpoint and correct issues that are often invisible to the naked eye.

The second type:

> This type of camera has an infrared sensitive video sensor somewhat like a FLIR camera, but is a far cheaper variant. More importantly, instead of depending on the weak infrared light generated by warm objects, IR security cameras **depend on reflected infrared light.** Since there's not enough ambient infrared light even on the hottest and brightest

Bold mine.

So it the infrared led is like the flash for taking pictures with usual cameras at low ambient light.
>

Comment: My understanding of the LEDs is that it's basically the same as having a camera with spotlights ringed around the lens; but in this case the light from it is non-disruptive to humans in the night, so it's better than having a bunch of LEDs shining on whatever you are watching.